# composite index is not work in range query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query:

```
Select * 
from table 
where  a>10 and b=10
```

composite  Index is `(a,b)`.  My question is why it can only use  this conposite index in `a>10`，and `b=10` is not using the composite index  in explain plan.       I figure that even  when  `a>10`， `b` is also ordered in B+ tree， so why not using indexg in field `b`

Comment: Is it using a different index?

Comment: Just one composite index      （a,b）,I want to know why b cannot use this index

Comment: Just one composite index， I wanna know why  （a,b） can not be used in B+ tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `(a, b)` index, the B-tree looks like:

```
a:  1 -
    b:  1
        2
        4
        5
        10
        15
    5 -
    b:  2
        11
        22
    15 -
    b:  3
        10  **
        20
    20 -
    b:  5
        9
        10  **
        11
```

To find all the rows where `a > 10 AND b = 10` it has to first partition the `a > 10` level of the tree, then go through each of these subtrees to get its `b = 10` element.

WIth an index `(b, a)` the B-tree would look like:

```
b:  1 -
    a:  1
    2 -
    a:  1
        5
    4 -
    a:  1
    5 -
    a:  1
        20
    9 -
    a:  20
    10 -
    a:  1
        15  **
        20  **
    11 -
    b:  5
        20
    20 -
    b:  15
    22 -
    b:  5
```

Now it can simply find `b = 10` in the first level of the tree, and partition its subtree to get `a > 10`. This doesn't require scanning multiple subtrees.

I've marked the selected rows with `**` in the two diagrams.  With your index, the rows are spread apart throughout the B-tree. With the reversed index, they're contiguous within the tree, and this is what the database needs in order to be able to use an index effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ref part of your indexes (aka `b`) before the range part (`a`). So the composite index should be `(b,a)`.

Both parts of the index create the B+ tree. So searching an `(a,b)` index would involve searching all of `a>10` for the `b=10` part.

If its `(b,a)`, you can find the  `b=10`, `a>10` and then just walk the tree until there is no more `b=10`.

Comment: I figure the cost of serching is the same between the two kind of index， could you explain it more clearly?  

Comment: [Query Optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization) has some good slides on the tree nature of btrees. And  [How MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)